# Oauth2 authentication for installed applications using service account flow

Tags: google-oauth

I've successfully built a ruby script and a mac app that use service account credentials to authenticate (without user interaction) to google cloud storage and upload/download objects.

I now need to perform similar actions on an iOS device. Is it possible to use installed application credentials to authenticate *still without user interaction?*

If it's possible or has been done, can you please provide an example or point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: that not how oauth works. users need to give explicit access permission to their google account.

Comment: Yes, and I've done that programatically in my first two projects, I'd like to know if it's possible to do it from an installed application...

Answer (score 0):

You need the private key for the service account to get the access token for the application. Please bear in mind that some hacker may steal that private key for both mac and iOS app. If the data is per user and you have a backend server, you may authenticate the user on the backend and then use the private key on the server to access the storage. If the data is per app, seems there is no good way to prevent the private key abuse.

Comment: It's the latter, and I know there's a risk in coding the private key into the app, but I absolutley need the app to programmatically authenticate without user interaction, and this is where I'm struggling because I haven't yet been successful in doing this nor can I find any examples out there...